# How do you link users to an external url in React when the url is custom to the user's input stored in a db?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a project that I'm working on that allows users to enter a custom url into a text input, which is then stored in MongoDB. I am trying to display the url inside a react component and also allow the user to click on the link and open it in a different window. However, every time I use an anchor tag, it links to localhost:3000/{url} in development and domain.com/{url} in production.

My current failed attempt is as follows:

```
{appUrl && (
            <li>
                <strong>Job URL</strong>: <a href={appUrl} target="_blank">{appUrl}</a>
            </li>
)}
```

I am struggling to find a solution after reading the React and React router docs. How can I handle this?

Comment: If it's an external url it should be has absolute url (including domain etc.)